# Please allow the use of <abbr>

Tags: feature-request

When describing certain features of a language, a lot of meta information is needed, which either has to be given in brackets, links or an additional sentence.

In the cases of

- using abbrevations (jmd)
- using a strong localized word (ARGE, Leintuch)
- introducing german words in an English Q/A (as fast translation)

it would be helpful to simply use the `<abbr>` and the `<acronym>` [HTML tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Phrase_elements) or have some funky Markup syntax for it (like [ARGE|Arbeitsamt in Deutschland]).

Therefore my feature request: Introduce those two elements and add some Markup syntax for it.

Comment: Mir ist dabei nicht ganz klar, wie du das einsetzen willst.

Comment: Die Idee ist, dass man die Langform mit Maustext bekommt?

Comment: Genau. Der markierte Text (im Beispiel ARGE) wird strichliert unterlegt und wenn man die Maus draufhält wird einem der Langtext in einem Hint angezeigt. So wie das zB bei den Bearbeitungslinks der Fall ist.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I would approve this idea, given that those tags do no harm but are indeed a useful addition. However I don’t think they are that useful on this site. I don’t really believe that anyone would really bother to write something like `[jmd|jemand]` or `[jmdn|jemanden]`, especially not all the time. At least I would rather just write the full word in those cases, and maybe introduce my abbreviation for the following text: `jemand (*jmd*)`.

Unless there is an automatic conversion for words, which won’t happen, because such automatic conversions won’t work for german words (given that SE itself is english focussed), I highly doubt such a feature would be accepted enough to be of any use. And in general I would object others editing posts just to add those abbreviation tags.

Comment: Apparently, at least Samuel would use it. I think a lot of titles would look neater with "jmd." than the full "jemandem", so spelling it out isn't always desirable.

Comment: @Tim N: But formatting is not applied to titles. So if you want this because of titles, it won't work at all.

Comment: The real cool feature would be if you could introduce the abbrevation once and the parser would mark it for followings too ;) But as we see with wikipedia links and references are made only once (at their first appearance) to not clutter text and markup. That's what I'd go for too.